# Disable built-in authenticator error for unauthorized users Yii2

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-basic-app

I have a controller with many actions. Now I want to use token-based authentication so I changed the behavior like this:

```
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        'authenticator' => [
            'class' => CompositeAuth::className(),
            'only' => [
                'logout',
                'revoke'
            ],
            'authMethods' => [
                HttpBasicAuth::className(),
                HttpBearerAuth::className(),
                QueryParamAuth::className(),
            ],
        ]
    ];
}
```

This code works well but there is one problem.
I want to handle the unauthorized users by myself (not Yii) but when there is an unauthorized user send a request to my action, my action doesn't work and it will return Yii's default error.

How can I tell Yii to just authenticate the user (because I want to use `Yii::$app->user->isGuest`) and don't send default error?

UPDATE: I just want to disable the authenticator errors, I need other errors.

`Yii2`

`PHP 7.2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use [`$optional`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-filters-auth-authmethod#$optional-detail) property to configure actions where authentication should be optional (should not throw error). If it should be optional for all actions, you may use `*` instead of action name:

```
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        'authenticator' => [
            'class' => CompositeAuth::className(),
            'optional' => ['*'],
            // ...
        ]
    ];
}
```